# Unable to connect to remote redis (with rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

Im trying to use redis with rails and namespacing. 
In my application.rb I put :

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store, 'redis://localhost:6379/0/cache', { expires_in: 90.minutes }
```

Here localhost is redis in windows where I am developing my rails project.

and in my config/initializers/redis.rb:

```
$redis = Redis::Namespace.new("my_app_name", :redis => Redis.new)
```

and from my controllor I can access it perfectly.

```
$redis.set("foo","bar")
word=$redis.get("foo")
puts word -------> output is "bar".
```

But I am unable to access Redis on another linux server instead of localhost.
I tried to do :

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store, 'redis://that_server_ip:6379/0', { expires_in: 90.minutes }
```

Bu I keep getting

```
Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Redis::TimeoutError)).
```

Comment: can you post your /etc/hosts file both on your localhost and that_server?

Comment: hosts file won't matter when using IP addreses. "//that_server_ip:6379".

Answer (score 0):

you need to expose your port through firewall, use `iptables` or `ufw`

[UPDATED]

can you post your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: I am fairly new to redis. Plz explain the two terms further

Comment: These are OS level firewall tools, not redis ones. And as long as your app is trying to connect to localhost these won't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says it is still trying to connect to localhost and that is failing. You may need to restart your app to take in the new config.

Comment: I tried restarting the app. Still tries to connect to local host.

Comment: That would mean it isn't recognizing the new config, or you need to configure it in a different location/manner.  I a,not a ruby guy but looking at https://github.com/redis/redis-rb makes me think the call to connection create in your redis.rb needs to pass it the connection details.